# BackButton Stretchable

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, ios5

i want a stretchable back button i'm now using this line of coding, this is giving me a back button but i want it stretchable with a custom title in it so i tried to add this line in the code

```
[button setTitle:@"back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But it didn't work

```
   UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 16, 0, 16)];

    //create the button and assign the image
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:buttonImage  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //buttonImage.size.width
    //set the frame of the button to the size of the image (see note below)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```

In the NavigationBar it display's i need a title inside so it can stretch?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Cylbz.png]

Comment: How didn't it work? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @AshFurrow Screenshot in the first post!

Comment: -1 This isn't even a question, its a statement

Comment: Have you tried increasing the width of the button's `frame`? 30 points seems pretty small if it has a title...

Comment: @omz sorry i need a title inside it, the 30 must be buttonImage.size.width

Comment: No, the 30 is the entire width of the button, the button image doesn't really have a fixed width, because it's _stretchable_.

Comment: @omz ok thanks but i need a title in the button..

Comment: Then you need to make the button wide enough that the title fits. 30 points obviously isn't enough.

Comment: So you have changed the width then?

Comment: @omz the 'back' txt is showing up but not IN my BUTTON

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11471/discussion-between-jones-and-omz)

Comment: @omz yes i changed the width of the button, but the text is not displaying iN my button

Comment: Show a screenshot of how your button actually looks.

Comment: @omz http://i.imgur.com/X96rp.png

Comment: Ah, I see. You have to set the button's _background_ image, e.g. `[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]`.

Comment: @omz thanks, but the button now looks like http://i.imgur.com/pJEil.png

Comment: A my bad, @omz post your answer as an answer below so i can accept it! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `setBackgroundImage:forState` instead of `setImage:forState:` if you want your image to be stretchable.

You should also set the width of the button to a higher value that allows your title to fit. As the image is stretchable, the button doesn't have to have the same size as the image.